# Подскажите как посчитать сумму чисел строк в двумерном массиве java и сравнить их между собой, что найти максимальную

Tags: java, массивы, случайные-числа, max

пока есть такой код из 12 строк и 8 столбцов с сгенерированными случайными значениями, мне необходимо посчитать сумму каждой строки, сравнить эти суммы, и индекс самой максимальной по сумме строчки вывести на экран

```java
public class Task3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int m = 12;
        int n = 8;
        int[][] numbers = new int [m][n];
        int sum = 0;
        for(int i=0; i< numbers.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < numbers[i].length; j++) {
                numbers[i][j] = rand.nextInt(51);
                System.out.print(numbers[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println(`введите сюда код`);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

В цикле проходите по всем строкам и считаете сумму чисел в каждой строке. Как только посчитали сумму - сравниваете с переменной для максимума. Всё.
Собственно вложенные циклы у вас уже есть, добавьте только подсчет суммы и поиск максимума.
Ну и поскольку сгенерированный массив вы никуда не возвращаете, его можно и не выделять.

Comment: Чтобы сравнить с максимальной, нужно ее (максимальную) сначала найти

Comment: Перед циклом переменной для максимума присваиваете очень маленькое значение, например `INT_MIN`. Т.е. `int max = INT_MIN;`. Нашли сумму первой строчки, сравнили с переменной, если сумма больше, то в переменную записали сумму. Потом вторую строчку и т.д. Это и есть поиск максимума.

Comment: `INT_MIN` - это C/C++, а здесь Java. Обычно инициирующее значение берут из самого массива - в данном случае можно взять сумму первой строки.

Comment: @АлексейР  Да, спутал, спасибо что указали. Но думаю в java тоже есть константы. Можно и значение первой строки взять, просто это тяжелее словами описать. А код я хочу чтобы автор вопроса сам написал.

Comment: @АлексейР Нашел - эта константа в Java - `java.lang.Integer.MIN_VALUE;`

Answer (score 1):

Если программа большая, то имеет смысл уменьшить количество работы для неё и почитать сумму поэлементно:

```
Random rand = new Random();
    int m = 12;
    int n = 8;
    int[][] numbers = new int [m][n];
    int sum = 0;
    int max = 0;
    for(int i=0; i< numbers.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < numbers[i].length; j++) {
             numbers[i][j] = rand.nextInt(51);
             System.out.print(numbers[i][j] + " ");
             sum += numbers[i][j];
        }
        System.out.println();
        if (sum > max) {
            max = sum;
            m = i;
        }
    sum = 0;
    }
    System.out.print(String.format("Индекс строки с максимальной суммой элементов [%s]", m));
```

Comment: А если сумма чисел в строках не превысит 0, `m` останется равен 12 с самого начала программы. А вы видите, что массив локальный и никуда не передается из функции? А зачем его тогда создавать и хранить? А чтобы искать сумму и среди отрицательных элементов нужно инициализировать max минимальным значением для int - `int max = java.lang.Integer.MIN_VALUE;`

Comment: Если сумма не превысит 0, то можно таким же образом преобразовать второй код из ответа выше. Просто, не хотела создавать второй "мемуар" (длинный ответ).
Массив никуда в этом коде не передаётся - да, но ответ я дала в соответствии с вопросом.

Comment: @DmytriK, `Random.nextInt` НЕ возвращает отрицательные числа, а только в диапазоне `[0; n - 1]`, то есть в данном случае, от 0 до 50 _включительно_.